# HTCondor Shadow exception : [Errno 8] Exec format error

Tags: python, format, condor

I am new for HTcondor, after I submit a job via Putty, the job is being put on hold, the log file says the error below:

```
007 (274036.000.000) 06/28 23:12:08 Shadow exception!
    Error from slot1@hana-******: Failed to execute '/var/lib/condor/execute/dir_107122/condor_exec.exe': (errno=8: 'Exec format error')
     0  -  Run Bytes Sent By Job
     16520  -  Run Bytes Received By Job
     ...

012 (274036.000.000) 06/28 23:12:08 Job was held.
     Error from slot1@hana-2.*******: Failed to execute'/var/lib/condor/execute/dir_107122/condor_exec.exe': (errno=8: 'Exec format error')
     Code 6 Subcode 8
     ...
```

below is my submit description file:

```
# defining the programm
cmd = /***/my_prog.ipynb
# defining the parameters

#args = /***/model_1/data_1.csv
#args = /***/model_2/data_2.csv
#args = /***/model_3/data_3.csv
#args = /***/model_4/data_4.csv
# defining memory requirements
request_memory = 100 GB
# defining to use 1 CPU
request_cpus = 100
# defining the max. run time of the job
+REQUESTED_WALLTIME = 72
# defining the mail address for notification
notify_user = ***@**.com
notification = Always
should_transfer_files = if_needed
when_to_transfer_output = on_exit
output = $(Cluster)-$(Process)_job.out
error = $(Cluster)-$(Process)_job.error
log = $(Cluster)-$(Process)_job.log
queue 1
```

In this case, the my_prog.ipynb itself has the code to read the local four files as input, meanwhile, the my_prog.ipynb also contains "print" command to write the results in a local file.

Base on this situation, i am really confuse should i also configure the args in the submit description files?

Please give me any small hint, this problem makes me tough for 3 days...

any suggestion would be thankful !

Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

In my case I got this error because the job was a python script and it did not have a shebang as the first line.

Answer (score 0):

Check the execute permissions on your executable.  I think the shadow log is showing that the executable bit is not set.

Answer (score 0):

For me, my `executable` was a bash script.

Similarly to Larry Martell's situation, shebang was missing from the first line.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
<the rest of your code here>
```

Hope this helps. Cheers.